# To check overlap function on coin and if they overlap then the previous coin goes to it's initial position using pandas & tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

```
i1 = pd.self.r1
i2 = pd.self.b1
if(i1.overlaps(i2)): 
   self.create_canvas.move(self.b1, 135, 250)
```

> Here self.r1,self.b1 are different color coin r1 is red's 1st coin similarly b1 is for blue
> This is just the part of code where I'm stuck.
>
> I want to check whether the previous coin and the coin which moved now overlap. If they overlap, then the previous coin must move to its box back.

> for more please view the code here :- [click here](https://codefile.io/f/7DOEp5U0b6QN1N7Dv0jd)

Comment: whoever is not able to find the code of my whole program please click on this link :- https://codefile.io/f/7DOEp5U0b6QN1N7Dv0jd

Comment: If you want to see if 2 circles overlap: `(circle_a.x-circle_b.x)**2 + (circle_a.y-circle_b.y)**2 <= circle_a.radius + circle_b.radius`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TheLizzard  since the circles have been created using tkinter oval so the circle doesn't have any radius. that's the problem

Comment: @Suraj You created the circles so you can keep track of their radius.

Comment: @TheLizzard I created the circle using the oval function which doesn't asked for any radius.

Comment: @Suraj `create_oval` method takes in 4 coordinates. If they are circles instead of ovals, you must be able to find the radius of the circles from your `.create_ovel` code. Like look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54039472/11106801) - in that case `r` is the radius. If you edit your question with the code that creates the circles, I will be able to work out the radius for you.

Comment: @TheLizzard its in the 1226th line the first cirle that's red I may type it for you, the following is the code for red circle:-

self.create_canvas.create_oval(67, 58, 91, 83, width=3, fill="#ff0000", activewidth=4, activefill="#ff0000")

and Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Suraj That is not a perfect circle. It's radius is 12 in the x-axis and 12.5 in the y-axis. The easiest solution is to take the radius as 12. If that doesn't look right, you might need to use 15 or 16 because of the `width`

Comment: @TheLizzard I've total of 16 circles it would be difficult for me to give random radius to each one of them by considering approximation.