# add method to existing class from external library

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, methods

I want to create a custom function working on the class Wm from the library Tkinter. the custom function is the following:

```
def centerw(width, height):
    screen_width = tk.Wm.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = tk.Wm.winfo_screenheight()
    w = 2
    h = 2
    x = (screen_width/w) - (width/w)
    y = (screen_height/h) - (height/h)
    self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
```

The function must be called with `root.centerw(300,400)` where root is the Tk() variable declared from the user. here is the snippet from the `__init__.py`:

```
def wm_geometry(self, newGeometry=None):
        """Set geometry to NEWGEOMETRY of the form =widthxheight+x+y. Return
        current value if None is given."""
        return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
```

so basically i'm trying to take advantage of the Wm class to create my custom function working with the code from init.py
goal: when i change the variable "root", i don't have to change anything inside my function

tried adding the function directly to the _*init*.py but there's no way to do that for me

Comment: Look up [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985217/11106801)

Answer (score 1):

Using monkey patching you can do something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def centerw(self, width, height):
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
    w = 2
    h = 2
    x = (screen_width/w) - (width/w)
    y = (screen_height/h) - (height/h)
    self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
tk.Wm.centerw = centerw


# Test:
root = tk.Tk()
root.centerw(300, 400)
```

If you save that into a file and import it, it will create a new method in `tk.Wm` named `centerw`. When that method is called, it will call your function with the same name and you can do anything there.

Even better, you can do something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def centerw(self):
    self.update_idletasks()
    width = self.winfo_width()
    height = self.winfo_height()
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
    w = 2
    h = 2
    x = (screen_width/w) - (width/w)
    y = (screen_height/h) - (height/h)
    self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
tk.Wm.centerw = centerw


# Test:
root = tk.Tk()
root.centerw()
```

That gets the `width` and `height` of the window (in this case `self`) and uses that instead of arguments passed in. I also had to add `self.update_idletasks()` to force `tkinter` to update its `width` and `height` otherwise `self.winfo_width()` will just return `1`.

---

Things to note:

- `root.xxx()` always passes in the object instance (in this case `root`) as the first argument. In methods, we usually call that `self`
- You can save this as `tkinter_centerw_patch.py` and use `import tkinter_centerw_patch` in your main python file to add the `centerw` method to `tk.Wm`